# Python 3.6 Functions

Tags: python

hi I have a function I have made and would like to know how I can get the var saved from a input out of the function like this

```
def Func1():
    name1 = input("Enter Name?")
    print(sr1)

Func1()
print(sr1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you just need to `return` the variable

```
def Func1():
    name1 = input("Enter Name?")
    return name1

sr1 = Func1()
print(sr1)
```

So `name1` is a local variable that only exists in the scope of the function `Func1`. You can use the `return` value to assign it back to the variable `sr1` that exists outside the function when you call it.